# Google Sheets formula not working

Tags: google-sheets

Google Sheets is saying there is a parse error.

```
    =ROUNDUP(B9/B3)&ʺ:ʺ&ROUNDUP(B3/B9)
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your formula is correct. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may just be the wrong type of double inverted commas. Try copy/pasting the following:

```
=ROUNDUP(B9/B3)&":"&ROUNDUP(B3/B9)
```

For comparison:

```
=ROUNDUP(B9/B3)&ʺ:ʺ&ROUNDUP(B3/B9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seconded, the commas are the issue here!

I re-typed your exact formula and the cell generated the correct solution:

> =roundup(B9/B3)&":"&roundup(B3/B9)